# Dual Graphs of T-fixed Stable Maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-space

The following screenshot is taken from "Localization of Virtual Classes" paper of Graber and Pandharipande. I don't understand the following highlighted sentences. From those sentences I understand that non-contracted rational components can not have marked points, I don't understand why. Could somebody help whether I am misunderstanding? If I understand sentences correctly, why does non-contracted rational components not have marked points on them?

[image: Dual Graph of T-Fixed Stable Maps]

Comment: Where do you get your claim about non-contracted rational components?

Comment: Non-contracted components(which must be rational) correspond to edges in the graph. Vertices correspond to some union of contracted components and some points. The sentence "These legs are attached to appropriate vertex." made me think that there should not be any marked points associated to edges hence non-contracted components.

Comment: I guess I see the reason why non-contracted components does not have a marked point. We can find a sequence stable maps by pre-composition with the isomorphism which is identity on the complement of the contracted component and on the contracted component of the source curve it is $\Phi(z)=nz$ or $\Phi(z)=\frac{z}{n}$. This gives a constant sequence on the moduli space of stable maps, but the limit of the marked points are nodes of the non-contracted component. This implies that component does not have marked points.

Comment: I really don't think that follows: the vertices correspond to the $\bf T$-invariant points, to which the marked points necessarily map. Any vertex lies at the intersection of rational components, but having the legs on the vertices just tells us that the markings are not at arbitrary points of the components, but specifically at the nodes where two components intersect. Does this seem to square away with your understanding?

Comment: Then I should paraphrase my question and say I don't understand why must marked points map to T-fixed points?

Comment: This is directly stated in lines 5-6. It's then stated in lines 6-7 that the only $\bf T$-fixed points are $p_0,...,p_r$.

Comment: Let me summarize what I understand and what I don't: I understand that non-rational components must be mapped to fixed points, this follows from Riemann-Hurwitz formula. I understand nodes must be mapped to fixed points, there are two cases that must be analyzed, the less easy one is nodes between rational components. I just don't understand why marked points must be mapped to fixed points. If understand that that will resolve my question that why we don't have any marked points on the non-contracted components. But you kind of convinced me it shouldn't be hard to see this as well. Thanks.

Comment: I will think more on it and I guess drawing a diagram will help me.

Comment: I guess I see the reason now. When $r=1$ I just need to think about the maps $f:\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ given by $f([z_0:z_1])=[z_0^d:z_1^d]$. If we have the diagonal action on the target with weights $\lambda_0,\lambda_1$ then the composition without marked points is isomorphic to $f$ only via action with weights $\frac{\lambda_0}{d}, \frac{\lambda_0}{d}$. But this morphism only fixes $[1:0]$ and $[0:1]$ so these are the only possible marked points. Using this we can show the same thing for any $r$.

Comment: I guess my above comment about the $\Phi_n(z)=nz$ thing is wrong. It has nothing to do with the T-action. And it can't be true in the general case otherwise there wouldn't be stable maps with rational components with marked points if the rational component has nodes. If we precompose with $\Phi_n(z)=nz$, I guess a new twig will occur in the limit and marked points are going to pass to new twig and the original twig will be contracted on the source since it won't satisfy the stability condition, so we will have an isomorphic stable map with marked points on the rational component again.